# Serialization of parallel integers

Tags: arrays, math, serialization

I would like to serialize parallel information like 1,23,5,32,6,1,0,5,1,6 into one single integer ("index" from now on).

The array has always exactly ten evalues and the order of the values matters. The values of the array are integers that can reach from 0 to +inf and are completely independent from each other.

I thought through a few possible solutions, but I can't come up with a solution where every possible array has exactly one possible index and where every possible index has exactly one possible array.

You can imagine the situation like ten ordered boxes in a row in which specific numbers of balls were put. Now there is an infinite number of these rows and each of the row has a different number of balls in the boxes. How can you give each of the rows one number (like a catalogue) and you exactly know how many balls are in which box?

I know that the index number is going to be ridiculously big with big array values, but I won't use big array values anyway.

examples:

```
Index: array
0: (0,0,0,0...,0,0)
1: (0,0,0,0...,0,1)
```

There should be a simple mathematical solution to this, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just interleave the digits. Example with arrays of size 3 instead of 10:

```
(123, 456, 789) --> 147258369
```

insert leading zeros if necessary:

```
(123, 4, 5) --> 100200345
```

Comment: this is exactly the obvious answer i was looking for, but didn't see. (Although it only works perfectly if you know how many digits the maximum values have. therefore the solution doesn'T work with infinite "rows" very good) Thank You! :D

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by henrik assumes that you know the maximum number of digits for a number, if you already know that then no need to interleave, just concatenate the numbers padded with  zeros.

I have a general construct :) Assume only two dimensions and arrange the pairs like this and maintain two integers. 
`(0,0) \\offset:0 -- sum:0`
 
`(0, 1), (1, 0) \\offset:1+0 -- sum:1`
`(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0) \\ offset:1+2 -- sum:2`

so essentially the index for a tuple is the index+offset where offset is determined by the level(fibbonacci(level), the level is determined by the sum of the terms, the index is determined by the ordering. (Offset+index) is guaranteed to be unique and can be decoded by dynamic programming

For more than two dimensions just recursively collapse dimensions, get an integer for first two dimensions this reduces your problem by 1 dimension and then you can keep going :)